# How to find out how many times a user touched an image

Tags: uibutton, uitouch

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
   UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint touchlocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];
```

How would you know when a user touched a certain button and how many times if i have four different buttons.

Comment: you can set the tag for each image initially and on touch check the condition for particular tag...

Answer (score 1):

I'm into C# so forgive me if I'm wrong, but couldn't you just increase an integer whenever the user clicks on an image, then if you wanted to know the amount of clicks, you'd look at this integer?

Answer (score 0):

what you will have to do is take one integer in.h file then in .m file write touchesbegan method like below.

```
  - (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
   CGPoint touchlocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];
  if([touch isKindOfClass:[UIImage class]])
  {
     myInt++;//your global integer....
  }
}
```

let me know it is working or not!!!

Happy Coding!!!!

Comment: - (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    gameState=gameRun;

    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    
 
    if ([touch view] == btnRed)
    {
        redTouch=redTouch+1;
        NSLog(@"%i",redTouch);
    
    }
if ([touch view] == btnYellow)
{
    yellowTouch=yellowTouch+1;
        NSLog(@"%i",yellowTouch);
    
}
 if ([touch view] == btnGreen)
{
    greenTouch=greenTouch+1;
        NSLog(@"%i",greenTouch);
    
}

if ([touch view]==btnBlue)

{    NSLog(@"%i",blueTouch);
    blueTouch=blueTouch+1;
}
}
I used this but still dosent log anything

Comment: what us btnRed ? is it button on imageview?

Comment: I tried your code it counts any touch on the screen not on the button

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this one..

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

    // ----------you can find using tag and first set button's tag in xib ------
    if(touch.view.tag == btnRed.tag)
    {
       redTouch++:
    }
}
```

Comment: - (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    gameState=gameRun;

    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    
 
    if ([touch view] == btnRed)
    {
        redTouch=redTouch+1;
        NSLog(@"%i",redTouch);
    
    }
if ([touch view] == btnYellow)
{
    yellowTouch=yellowTouch+1;
        NSLog(@"%i",yellowTouch);
    
}
 if ([touch view] == btnGreen)
{
    greenTouch=greenTouch+1;
        NSLog(@"%i",greenTouch);
    
}

if ([touch view]==btnBlue)

{    NSLog(@"%i",blueTouch);
    blueTouch=blueTouch+1;
}
}

Comment: if you are not getting right then you can do it like this see in my edited answer.

Comment: i got your solution you know when u click on button in this case this method is not fire so you need to add UITapGestureRecognizer to your all button.

Comment: I used this when i click on anywhere on the view it increases all count variables for each button

Comment: add tap gesture to your all buttons not on your view.

Comment: [redBtn addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];